# VC ++ express, how do I fix this error?

Tags: c++, build-process, build-error

I have experience programming in C#, but I'm taking a C++ class this semester, and I'm writing my second project, but I keep getting this error when I try to build a debug configuration of my program.

My build log is below, any ideas on what's going on? I'm at a loss.

Thanks everyone!

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Project_2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Deleting intermediate and output files for project 'Project_2', configuration 'Debug|Win32'
1>Compiling...
1>main.cpp
1>Linking...
1>LINK : C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project_2\Debug\Project_2.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>Embedding manifest...
1>Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 31 returned from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mt.exe'.
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project_2\Project_2\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Project_2 - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You need to show us the content of the build log: file://c:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project_2\Project_2\Debug\BuildLog.htm

Comment: Hmm, it seems the error has disappeared, I cleaned my project so I don't have the build log, but for future ref I will check the build log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the buildlog.htm file that is given in the build output. It will give you more (useful) information about what has happened.

Comment: The error has disappeared, but for future reference I will definitely check the build log, coming from C#, I didn't think about this. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft blames [antivirus](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=363060) for a similar case.

Comment: hmm...interesting, I'll take a look at this.

Comment: Actually, this could be the problem, I just told my Antivirus to ignore my VC++ directory. We'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

try setting your AV to ignore your project directories instead of VC++ directory.

Answer (score 1):

> Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 31 returned from 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mt.exe'.

Faced the same issue Cleaning the rebuilding solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off the Microsoft Security Essentials and the problem is gone. 
Strange that it only happened for the debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've meet similar problem in my build pipeline, the error was thrown for 95-99% of the builds. It looks like there was a problem in mt.exe assosociated with locked files from previous build steps; If mt.exe was executed with 5s delay there was no problem at all. I've noticed, that the problem may be fixed by introducing some delay in build or  by replacing the binary with mt.exe from v7.1 SDK